# PSEXEC credentials delegation issue when running exe on remote machine

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, psexec

I have a simple exe that just connects to SQL server and executes a `select` on a remote machine. In my scenario I have three machines: `A`,`B`, and `C`.

I am ruining `PSExec` from machine `A` as below:

```
& C:\PSTools\PSExec.exe \\MachineB C:\connectsql.exe -u username -p password
```

The exe, when executed on machine `B`, tries to connect to SQL server on machine `C` (based on the connection string I specified in the exe), which includes username and password as below:

```
"Data Source=machineC;Initial Catalog=AllDocs;Integrated Security=SSPI;User id=username;Password=pwd;"
```

Usernames and passwords are correct. But I get this error:

```
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

But If I change the connection string in the exe to connect to SQL server on machine `B` itself, I do not see the issue.

Also, If I run the exe locally on Machine B it successfully connects to SQL on Machine C.

Any idea how I can get away with this issue, so that When `PSExec` runs on machine `A`, the exe from machine `B` should able to connect to sql on machine `C`?

Comment: `Integrated Security=SSPI;` in your connection string means that you are attempting to connect via Windows Authentication.  Since you are providing the `User id` and `Password`, you can remove `Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Comment: I tried removing Integrated Security=SSPI; from connection string and ran it locally on machine B, and it now complains that "Login failed for user with "username""

Comment: Resolved by setting below in WindowsServer 2008r2:- Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only) .